# Automatic add text on textbox when I open one site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

So, i'm tring to put one information on one textbox, in more special textbox, CNPJ of one site:

> http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp

but I'm not getting... so, what I have tried... I have tried to put the cnpj value on the final of link, like this:

> http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp?cnpj=00495835000160

but, the site no put the value on the text box...

How I can make to enter with with the cnpj value on the site ( whiout digit on the site, just in the link... )

And, In C# I have tried this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ReceitaFederal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp");

                string strPost = "cnpj=00495835000160";

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                writer.Write(strPost);

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();

                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            }
            catch (Exception exec)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exec.GetType() + "" + exec.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That site has captcha protection, nothing you can do will get around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!!! First add this cookie container:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsultaCNPJ
{
    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer _mContainer;

        public void SetCookieContainer(CookieContainer container)
        {
            _mContainer = container;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            var webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.CookieContainer = _mContainer;
                webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Then edit you code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsultaCNPJ
{
    public class ConsultaCNPJBroker
    {
        private readonly CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
        public String DominioReceitaFederal = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br";
        public String GetDataReceitaFederal = "/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp";
        public String PostDataReceitaFederal = "/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp";
        private String _viewState;

        public Bitmap GetCaptcha()
        {
            const string strViewState = "<input type=hidden id=viewstate name=viewstate value='";
            const string strImagemCaptcha = "<img border='0' id='imgcaptcha' alt='Imagem com os caracteres anti robô' src='";
            String htmlResult;

            using (var wc = new CookieAwareWebClient())
            {
                wc.SetCookieContainer(_cookies);
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive] = "300";
                htmlResult = wc.DownloadString(DominioReceitaFederal + GetDataReceitaFederal);
            }

            if (htmlResult.Length > 0)
            {
                _viewState = htmlResult;

                int posString = _viewState.IndexOf(strViewState, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                _viewState = _viewState.Substring(posString + strViewState.Length);
                posString = _viewState.IndexOf("'>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                _viewState = _viewState.Substring(0, posString);

                String urlImagemCaptcha = htmlResult;
                posString = urlImagemCaptcha.IndexOf(strImagemCaptcha, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                urlImagemCaptcha = urlImagemCaptcha.Substring(posString + strImagemCaptcha.Length);
                posString = urlImagemCaptcha.IndexOf("'>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                urlImagemCaptcha = urlImagemCaptcha.Substring(0, posString);
                urlImagemCaptcha = urlImagemCaptcha.Replace("amp;", "");

                if (urlImagemCaptcha.Length > 0)
                {
                    var wc2 = new CookieAwareWebClient();
                    wc2.SetCookieContainer(_cookies);
                    wc2.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)";
                    wc2.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive] = "300";
                    byte[] data = wc2.DownloadData(DominioReceitaFederal + urlImagemCaptcha);

                    return new Bitmap(
                        new MemoryStream(data));
                }
                return null;
            }
            _viewState = "";
            return null;
        }

        public Stream Consulta(string aCNPJ, string aCaptcha, bool removerEspacosDuplos)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(DominioReceitaFederal + PostDataReceitaFederal);
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
            request.Method = "POST";

            string fviewstate = _viewState;
            fviewstate = Uri.EscapeDataString((fviewstate));

            string postData = "";
            postData = postData + "origem=comprovante&";
            postData = postData + "viewstate=" + fviewstate + "&";
            postData = postData + "cnpj=" + new Regex(@"[^\d]").Replace(aCNPJ, string.Empty) + "&";
            postData = postData + "captcha=" + aCaptcha + "&";
            postData = postData + "captchaAudio=&";
            postData = postData + "submit1=Consultar&";
            postData = postData + "search_type=cnpj";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            return response.GetResponseStream();                
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!

Special thanks to my great friend CunhaW!

**Usage:**

First create a form with a PictureBox and a TextBox and the broker for captcha like this

```
private readonly ConsultaCNPJBroker _broker = new ConsultaCNPJBroker();
this.ImgCaptcha = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
this.TbxCaptcha = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

Then use like 2-Steps query, first get the Captcha then do the Query with the captcha

```
private void UpdateCaptcha()
{
    ImgCaptcha.Image = _broker.GetCaptcha();
    TbxCaptcha.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

A user interaction is need here to solve the captcha and fill the textbox and finally

```
private void BtnExecute_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var pessoaJuridica = _broker.Consulta(TbxCNPJ.Text, TbxCaptcha.Text, true);
        // here you can see props like pessoaJuridica.CNPJ
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe this help you, it's not working yet... but almost there...*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LeituraWeb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        String viewState;
        public String Dominio_ReceitaFederal = "http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/";
        public String GetData_ReceitaFederal = "pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp";
        public String PostData_ReceitaFederal = "pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/valida.asp";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int PosString;
            String StrViewState = "<input type=hidden id=viewstate name=viewstate value='";
            String StrImagemCaptcha = "<img border='0' id='imgcaptcha' alt='Imagem com os caracteres anti robô' src='";
            String UrlImagemCaptcha = "";
            String HtmlResult = "";

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()){
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(Dominio_ReceitaFederal + GetData_ReceitaFederal);
            }

            if (HtmlResult.Length > 0)
            {
                viewState = HtmlResult;

                // executando um crop do viewstate para utilizar no post
                PosString = viewState.IndexOf(StrViewState);
                viewState = viewState.Substring(PosString + StrViewState.Length);
                PosString = viewState.IndexOf("'>");
                viewState = viewState.Substring(0, PosString);

                //executando um crop na url da imagem 
                UrlImagemCaptcha = HtmlResult;
                PosString = UrlImagemCaptcha.IndexOf(StrImagemCaptcha);
                UrlImagemCaptcha = UrlImagemCaptcha.Substring(PosString + StrImagemCaptcha.Length);
                PosString = UrlImagemCaptcha.IndexOf("'>");
                UrlImagemCaptcha = UrlImagemCaptcha.Substring(0, PosString);
                UrlImagemCaptcha = UrlImagemCaptcha.Replace("amp;", "");                

                // populando a imagem do captcha dentro de um picturebox
                if (UrlImagemCaptcha.Length > 0)
                    pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Dominio_ReceitaFederal + UrlImagemCaptcha)));
            }
            else
            {
                viewState = "";
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Dominio_ReceitaFederal + PostData_ReceitaFederal);

            // Formatando o ViewState Recebido
            string fviewstate = viewState;
            fviewstate = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(fviewstate));

            // inserindo os campos a serem postados
            string postData = "";
            postData = postData + "origem=comprovante&";
            postData = postData + "viewstate=" + fviewstate + "&";
            postData = postData + "cnpj=00000000000000&";
            postData = postData + "captcha=000000&";
            postData = postData + "captchaAudio=&";
            postData = postData + "submit1=Consultar&";
            postData = postData + "search_type=cnpj";

            // montando a requisicao

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);           
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();           
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // ---------- erro aqui !!!
            // retorno da sefaz ---- sempre retorna -- Parametros Inválidos
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the target site supports the kind of request you are trying to do.

If not, you are out of luck. Keep in mind that the web app implementation is the one who dictates the rules, not you.

Additionally, it looks like you are trying to obtain information from a Brazilian government site. Usually, this type of sites have mechanisms to prevent what you are trying to achieve, such as [captchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) and domain validation.

The good news is that, also usually, government sites publish rules and manuals on how to access public webservices. However, you also usually need permission for that.

Comment: so, I don't whant to put the information on captcha, I just whant to put the information on CNPJ

Comment: @Alexandre You can't. The security mechanisms on the site (captcha) will only allow human interaction with that page.

Answer (score 0):

The page uses frames:

```html
<frame name="top" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0" marginheight="0" noresize="true" target="contents" src="cabecalho.htm" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<frame  frameborder="0" name="main" SRC="cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp" scrolling="auto" noresize="false" marginheight="0"  marginwidth="0">
```

The **main** frame contains the page **`cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp`**, so calling http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao2.asp?cnpj=00495835000160 (see the **2** in the page file name) will show you the content of the main frame with the CNPJ filled as passed by the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I say instead of crafting the resulting code, 
you could inject javascript.

e.g. 
open the page you posted
`http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/pessoajuridica/cnpj/cnpjreva/cnpjreva_solicitacao.asp`

open JS Console and type the following:

`document.getElementsByName("main")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByName("cnpj")[0].value = "MyNewValue"`

Notice, the form is within a `frame` element, so you need to get the frame element and then the input element.

You can do the same via the Web Browser API.

Good Luck with solving the CAPTCHA